# how we add types in nodejs and typescript in req res

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, mern

the repo of my project is
**https://github.com/Shahidkhan0786/kharidLoapp**

in my project the @types folder contain file (express.d.ts) in this file i add a types in response

in (express.d.ts) file in @types folder

```
export {}

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        // interface Request {
        //     auth: User;
        // }

        interface Response {
            Success(message: string, data?: any, responseCode?: number): void;
            Error(message: string, data?: any, responseCode?: number): void;
        }
    }
}
```

in my startappmiddleware

```
responseMiddleware(req:express.Request , res:express.Response , next:NextFunction){
        res.Success = (message: string ,data?:any , resCode?: number) => {
            resCode= resCode ? resCode: 200;
            res.status(resCode)
            .json({
                success: true,
                message,
                data
            })
        };


        res.Error = (message: string ,data?:any , resCode?: number) => {
            resCode= resCode ? resCode: 200;
            res.status(resCode)
            .json({
                success: true,
                message,
                data
            })
        };

        next();
    }
```

if i use error with response

[image]

i tried used this types with res but got error

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Express.Response` instead of `express.Response` in `responseMiddleware` arguments?

Comment: i have added this but not worked  

Answer (score 0):

Try [Ambient Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) + [Declaration Merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

`middlewares/response.ts`:

```
import express, { NextFunction } from 'express';

declare module 'express' {
  export interface Response {
    Success(message: string, data?: any, responseCode?: number): void;
    Error(message: string, data?: any, responseCode?: number): void;
  }
}

const responseMiddleware = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  res.Success = (message: string, data?: any, resCode?: number) => {
    resCode = resCode ? resCode : 200;
    res.status(resCode).json({
      success: true,
      message,
      data,
    });
  };

  res.Error = (message: string, data?: any, resCode?: number) => {
    resCode = resCode ? resCode : 200;
    res.status(resCode).json({
      success: true,
      message,
      data,
    });
  };

  next();
};
```

package versions:

```json
"express": "^4.17.1",
"@types/express": "^4.17.11",
"typescript": "^3.9.7",
```